# Eclipse CDT - show inherited members in derived class?

Tags: eclipse, class, show, radix, eclipse-cdt

is it possible in Eclipse CDT that the outline or even the code windows displays inherited members of a class? So that I have a full overview of the derived class functionality.

```
class Derived : public Base {}
```

If I'm in Derived.cpp/h I want to see the inherited members from Base.cpp/h in the outline (or somewhere else, maybe greyed out directly in the code window).

Having it in the auto-complete list is nice, but having also a full overview would be better.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

- F4 for full hierarchy view related to a class.
- Ctrl+T shows implementations for a selected member function.